# HVAC inside unit water leaking

Tags: hvac, condensate

I have an HVAC unit that has two parts.  The first is the outside unit that is the compressor.  In my basement, I have a second unit (I think the heating and forced air components).  Attached to the inside unit is a condensate pump.  Today, I heard water dripping in the inside unit and saw water leaking from the unit.  I discovered the drain pipe from the inside HVAC unit to the condensate pump was clogged.  I unclogged it and that now seems fixed. But, what about that water that I heard inside the HVAC unit?  It sounded like more than a drip (like there was a puddle in there).  Will that just get pumped out by the condensate pump or do I need to get a professional in here to remove that water?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  No need to worry about mold or anything?

Comment: @Gil make an answer out of that.

Comment: Well, I opened up the vent at the bottom of the unit and found about 3 gallons of water so I scooped that all out and I'm assuming the residual dampness will evaporate and the condensate pump will take care of the rest.  Thanks!

Comment: "No need to worry about mold?" No, not unless you see some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water collects in that pan (condensate pan) because of the air becoming 100% saturated at the air given pressure. Note: water will separate from air when it comes incontact with a surface below its dew point (by definition water is 100% saturated with moisture at that point or colder will cause water condenses out of the air. I do not know your system but I will take SWAG and say the coil is in the range of 35F. This condensation is not a one shot deal, as water condenses out the saturation point goes up but by moving air and it will quit condensing. However you system constantly replaces it with more moist air. This is to be expected during normal operation. That pan is connected to your drain tube which is there to take the water away and keep it from overflowing.

In summary you fixed it, give it a few days and all should clear up. The water will evaporate and pass through your system as a vapor. If the humidity is up water will condense and run into the condensate pump unless it gets plugged again. Something to check each spring.